Lookup tables: check by type id or type name?
TLDR: Should I check an entity's type by lookup_table.id or lookup_table.type_name?
I've learned that lookup tables are almost always preferrable to Enums due to their flexibility. However, I have some doubts about how to handle constraints on the "type" of an entity.
let's say I have the following relations:

Employee
Employee_type
Project

Every Project has a leader field referring to Employee's id column, and the following constraint:

Each project leader has to be an Employee of type "manager"

Which can only be enforced using a trigger.
If Employee_type was an enum field I could join Project and Employee on the leader's id, then check that type = 'manager'.
But I'm using a lookup table, something like:
id | type_name
-----------------------
1  | regular employee
2  | Manager
3  | Technician

so, when checking for the type I can either check by id:
Employee_type.id = 2 --2 stands for 'Manager'!


(-)rather obscure unless you specify the type's name in a comment
(-)relies on fact that id never changes
(+)allows to edit the type's display name without breaking code

The alternative is checking by type_name:
Employee_type.type_name = 'Manager'


(+)more human readable
(-)can't edit the type's name without breaking code

This same problem also pops up when making queries, compare:
SELECT name FROM Employee WHERE type = 2 --selects managers

with
--Join can be hidden with a view
SELECT * FROM Employee JOIN Employee_type WHERE type_name = 'Manager'

My take from all of this is that the flexibility granted by lookup tables comes with the risk of the lookup's structure changing, invalidating code relying on it all the way up to application level.
Is there a way to prevent this?
Notes:

for the sake of simplicity, let's assume that the type of an
employee always stays the same
I am aware that employee type could be modeled using a Manager table with a reference to the corresponding Employee row. The problem with this approach is that it doesn't scale well when there is a high number of subclasses, each with different relationships and little to no unique attributes


Do you also have a Unique Index on type_name so that, for example, ID 3 cannot be changed from Technician to Manager and really make a mess?

@HardCode yes I do; reasonably it makes no sense for two types to have the same name. The possibility of that oversight is a good argument to choose check by id over check by type_name though

You can add a redundant unique constraint on the lookup table over (id, type_name). Then you can drag the type_name into the referencing table, define the foreign key on both columns and put a check constraint on the type_name in the referencing table.
Yes, that is not pretty, because it requires to keep a redundant copy of the type_name.  Using a manager table like you envision is the better solution. You don't need to create such a table for all possible types.
Using a trigger is usually not a good solution: there is always a race condition unless you use SERIALIZABLE isolation or lock lots of rows.
